# IBM Worklight: HTTP Adapter retrieve UTF-8 xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I used Worklight 5.0.6 to create a HTTP adapter to retrieve a UTF-8 XML. However, it returns failed and no data is retrieved. But when I change the file to UTF-8 without BOM, it can be retrieved successfully.
(The XML already contains charset equal to UTF-8 in first line.)
Is it a limitation for adapter only retrieve XML in UTF-8 without BOM but not solely UTF-8? or it is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. The fix will be in 6.1.0 version.